# Is it valid to divide over this factor?

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, algebra-precalculus

Is it permissible for me to perform this operation:

$$z^nf(1/z) = {c}$$

$\implies$

$$f(1/z) = \frac{c}{z^n}$$

This is in the context of complex analysis, analyzing poles at infinity / zero.

If it is ok, is it *primarily* ok because I am in a complex variable setting, and in a real variable setting, it would not be valid? (And that the only way to divide over an $x^2$ or an $x^4$ is when the other side of the equation has a factor to cancel with?)

Thanks,

Comment: In both real and complex variables, you are allowed to do this with the express stipulation that $z\neq0$. This is a valid technique if you have that condition met. Things kind of fall apart otherwise. Of course, they fall apart beautifully in the complex plane, hence why poles are so useful.

Comment: Ah, so what I did is valid, since the pole (of order n) at z = 0 is not in the domain of definition of f(z) - is that what you mean, @terrahyde?  Thanks.

Comment: Yes. That is indeed what I was trying to say.

Comment: (So that the domain is a punctured plane ...)

Comment: Ok awesome - thanks so much @terrahyde!! :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although your main question has been answered in the comment, I'm afraid that your underlying misconception about division may still be there. Division is not actually something by itself. It is meant to be the inverse operation to multiplication, specifically that it will undo multiplication. This is only possible if you can determine the original before the multiplication. If you multiply a real number by two, you can undo it only because there is a unique possible real number that when multiplied by two would give the value that you have. But if you multiply a real number by zero, you cannot undo it.

So when you say "And that the only way to divide over an $x^2$ or an $x^4$ is when the other side of the equation has a factor to cancel with?" it is completely false. Consider the equation "$x^4 = x^2$". By your claim we can divide both sides by $x^2$ without changing its meaning, which results in $x^2 = 1$. But that is clearly wrong.

And when doing mathematics, the question you should be asking is not "When can we do this or that?" but "Why can we claim this or that?" and "Why should we bother about this or that?". In the context of the above example, "Why can we undo multiplication by $x^2$?", and the answer is "No you cannot, unless $x^2 \ne 0$.".

Comment: This is such a beautiful answer to a very simple question that I suspect many other mathematics students get wrong, because we normally aren't taught to think of division in a slightly more abstract - and correct - way that you have suggested, @user21820.  Thanks so much for sharing :-)  Have a great day!

Comment: @LebronJames: Thanks for your kind words! I'm glad that I can make things clear for you and other people. You are indeed right that many students get wrong, and certainly it is not something that cannot be helped, if we can help it!